# Scraping an exact string with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, html-agility-pack, scrape

I'm trying to scrape the video tags from a YouTube video and it should be pretty simple even though I got stuck.
I couldnt find many documentations about what I was trying to find so now i'm asking you who have experience with HtmlAgilityPack.

The thing im trying to scrape it this.

```
video:tag" content="Comedy">
```

and all other `video:tag`

[image]

As you can see the tag is distinguishable.
However this is how far I got & I have no idea how to grab those tags.

How do I grab the first video tag and display it in a MessageBox.Show();

```
    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilh3hxNdpZs");

        htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("video:tag");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can tell that probably the issue is using the wrong method in the html document.
`htmlDoc.LoadHtml(...)` actually accepts as argument actual html/xml represented as string, not an uri to html page.

In your scenario you can try with the `HtmlWeb` class.
You can use

```
var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
```

`htmlWeb.Load(url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilh3hxNdpZs")` which will return instance of `HtmlDocument` with parsed html page.

The query of the video tags looks good, should match the video tags.

I hope this helps.